# Best oracle java build for Windows Server 2008

Tags: java

We have a test box that is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and a production box that is R2 Enterprise.  I would like to install the best VM for these hosts.  The production box has multiple CPUs and is visualized using VM Ware.  I doubt that I need the i586 build, that leaves these two:

jdk-6u26-windows-ia64.exe
jdk-6u26-windows-x64.exe

Is ia64 only for the higher-end Intel Itanium processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ia64 is Itanium
- x64 is 64-bit x86
- i586 is for 32-bit x86

You're down to deciding between using the x64 vs. the i586 version, and if you want to take advantage of being able to allocate a larger heap, then use the x64 version.

Check the [64-bit section of the Sun JVM FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_description) for some information as to why you'd want x64 over i586. The biggest difference is being able to allocate more heap space to the JVM, but there might be slight performance tradeoffs because the pointer size changes in the 64-bit JVM.